# React- why is the textbox not clearing when rendered?

Tags: reactjs

I wanted a reusable text component. My todo app is supposed to clear the textbox after creating a new item. So I setState with a updated list and a blank textbox. But textbox is not getting cleared.

The console.log line the textbox rendering with a blank string. But the old string lingers in place.

What is wrong?

```jsx
var Textbox = React.createClass({

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      text: ""
    };
  },

  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.props.callback(event.target.value);
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log("textbox render", this.props.text)
    return <div>
      <label>{this.props.label}</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        defaultValue={this.props.text}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>
  }
});
```

Here is excerpt of the method that adds an item, `this.state.newItem` is the state item that contains the text.

```jsx
  addNewItem: function() {
    console.log("add new");
    this.state.items.push({
      display: this.state.newItem,
      id: uuid()
    });
    this.setState({
      newItem: "",
      items: this.state.items
    });
  },
```

Of course, Textbox is rendered with `newItem`:
    return 
      
      add new

Comment: can you create a fiddle!

Comment: you should not mutate the state directly, instead create the object `var newItems = this.state.items;` and then `newItems.push({something})` and `this.setState({newItem: "", items: newItems}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the text of the textbox into its state using `onChange`, and then pass the textbox the prop `value={this.state.value}`. Then when you want to clear the textbox just set the value in state to `''`. You will probably want to have an initial state of `return {value:''};` So really, just take the default props you have and make it default state, etc.

Comment: This will create a controlled component, which I don't think OP wants.

Comment: OP is already using state in his code so figured he could just reuse it. This will be very ugly without state - see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: I was not suggesting removing his use of state.  You can use state with uncontrolled components too.